# Does converging in probability require $X_n$ and $X$ to be defined on the same space?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I read this passage regarding converging in distribution and it claims it is not necessary that $X_n$ and $X$ are defined on the same space (probability space). I read some examples and understood why that would be the case, by the way, I am not very advanced on measure theory.

Now I am wondering if the idea of **converging in probability** needs to be in the same space. I am particularly concerned in this question because if it doesn't stand then I can construct an example showing converging in distribution does not imply converging in probability by simply constructing random variables that are not on the same space.

I feel like converging in probability has to happen on the same probability space since we are exploring the idea od $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|\leq \epsilon).$ In particular, the probability measure has to be the same. However, I am not sure on this and if $(\Omega, F)$ need to be same, too. Could someone please explain to me in the easiest language as I am not looking for an advanced answer. Much thanks!

Comment: Regarding your concern: note that this implication indeed is not true, and none of the implications between modes of convergence is threatened by that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they have to be defined on the same probability space. The definition of convergence in probability is that for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$. The expression $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)$ alone requires them to be defined on the same probability space, otherwise it makes no sense.

Convergence in distribution is different, it is all about the distributions of the variables without any meaning to their actual values. So when we define this type of convergence we can indeed let the random variables be from different probability spaces, the only thing that matters here is their CDF.